# TableRow is being added but doesn't display

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a small app that periodically needs a table row added to the tablelayout.  Per the getChildCount() method the row is being added but it doesn't display.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

```
    TableLayout tbl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.mytbl);
    TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    TextView txtView = new TextView(this);


    row.setId(1234);
    row.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    row.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    row.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.darker_gray);


    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1.0f);
    ll.setId(1589);
    ll.setLayoutParams(lp); 
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    ll.setBackgroundResource(R.color.header_background);
    ll.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    String msg = "Sample Text";

    txtView.setId(657);
    txtView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    txtView.setTextColor(R.color.a_color);
    txtView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_a);
    txtView.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT);
    txtView.setText(msg);


    ll.addView(txtView);
    row.addView(ll);
    tbl.addView(row,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));//maybe add this with layout params tl.addView(tr,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

i've tried tbl.RequestLayout() and tbl.Invalidate() but no help.  The table is wrapped in a scrollview which is my best guess as to where the problem is. I've been tinkering with this for several hours so a nudge in the right direction sure would be helpful

```
    <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrVw_lst"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/mytbl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:stretchColumns="*">
```

Comment: Could you add the layout file where you have the parent `ScrollView` and the `TableLayout`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you run the code for adding a row in your `TableLayout`? I've simulated adding a row on a click of a `Button` and I get a awkward `Divide by 0`  exception.

Anyway, change the `LayoutParams`  of the enclosing `Linearlayout` to `TableRow.LayoutParams`(its parent is the `TableRow`):

```
    TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
            TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f);
    ll.setId(1589);
    ll.setLayoutParams(lp)
```

Also, if this doesn't solve the problem, try to add:

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

to the `ScrollView` tag in the xml layout.

Comment: Topeka! That worked without implementing fillviewport.   However, the scrolling hasn't kicked in yet so i may need it after adding x amount of rows.  I get the divide by zero error in my editor sometimes when i have a table with zero rows but goes away with a little fidgeting.  Thanks so much I've tinkered with this for hours