# How to retrieve all columns in TableLayout dynamically at Runtime in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-tablelayout

I want to fetch 14 column in table layout dynamically at runtime from SQLite. I tried but getting exception of ArithmeticException : divide by zero. I don't know where is the actual problem in table layout of mutateColumnsWidth.I surface the net but did not find proper solution.Can someone help me please. How to solve this.Thanks in Advanced.

Here is my activity code.

```
SQLiteDatabase sqlDatabase = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor c1 =sqlDatabase.rawQuery(performanceQuery , null);

          int rows = c1.getCount();
          Log.e("rows "," = " + rows);

          int cols = c1.getColumnCount();
          Log.e("cols "," = " + cols);

        if (c1 != null && c1.getCount() != 0) 
        {  
            Log.e("11111","11111");
            if (c1.moveToFirst())
            {   
                Log.e("222222","222222");
                // outer for loop
                  for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) 
                  {
                     TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
                      row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                 LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


                    // inner for loop
                       for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
                       {
                           TextView tv = new TextView(this);

                            tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                            tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape);
                            tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                            tv.setTextSize(18);
                          // tv.setTextColor(010101);
                           tv.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);

                            tv.setText(c1.getString(j));

                            String strText = tv.getText().toString().trim();
                            System.out.println(" strText " + strText);

                            row.addView(tv);


                       }
                       Log.e("3333333","3333333");
                       c1.moveToNext();

                       Log.e("4444444","4444444");
                       table_layout.addView(row);


                  }
            }
            sqlDatabase.close();
            c1.close();
            Log.e("55555555","55555555");
        }

Here is log error information

07-11 14:49:59.665: E/AndroidRuntime(328): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-11 14:49:59.665: E/AndroidRuntime(328): java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero
07-11 14:49:59.665: E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at android.widget.TableLayout.mutateColumnsWidth(TableLayout.java:579)
07-11 14:49:59.665: E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at android.widget.TableLayout.shrinkAndStretchColumns(TableLayout.java:568)
07-11 14:49:59.665: E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at android.widget.TableLayout.measureVertical(TableLayout.java:466)
07-11 14:49:59.665: E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at android.widget.TableLayout.onMeasure(TableLayout.java:431)
07-11 14:49:59.665: E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
07-11 14:49:59.665: E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:581)
07-11 14:49:59.665: E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:365)
07-11 14:49:59.665: E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
07-11 14:49:59.665: E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
07-11 14:49:59.665: E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
07-11 14:49:59.665: E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
07-11 14:49:59.665: E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
07-11 14:49:59.665: E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
07-11 14:49:59.665: E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
07-11 14:49:59.665: E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:839)
07-11 14:49:59.665: E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
07-11 14:49:59.665: E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-11 14:49:59.665: E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-11 14:49:59.665: E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-11 14:49:59.665: E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-11 14:49:59.665: E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-11 14:49:59.665: E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-11 14:49:59.665: E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-11 14:49:59.665: E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10461639/tablerow-is-being-added-but-doesnt-display It might help you.